# css margin-left propery - how to specify for various browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to align checkbox. When I give

```
margin-left : 10px; //proper with IE
```

It align itself properly in IE.

If I give

```
margin-left : 15px; //proper with chrome
```

This works proper with chrome.

Is there any way to sort this out so that I get proper alignment in both the browsers ?

Comment: Can you create a simple fiddle showing this problem?

Comment: Agreed.  Have you also considered setting a `width` to the `body`?

Comment: @Mr_Green: Better yet, a Stack Snippet (the `<>` toolbar button) here on site.

Comment: @SaucedApples Not to the body. But to the immediate div.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the checkboxes into a fieldset? This might solve all alignment issues by the browser itself.... See http://html.cita.illinois.edu/nav/form/checkbox/index.php?example=6 for an example.

Comment: Try setting `width: 100%` on `body{}` but also please drop us the code in http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Please don't try fix these small issues between browser, they all differs slightly and you'll get a big head ache if you try fix all those oddities, so just leave them be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are seperate hack codes for set styles for particular browsers,

for example,

assume checkBoxElement is the class of the checkbox input element,

**mozilla firefox**

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.checkBoxElement{
    margin-left : 10px; 
  }
}
```

**Chrome and Safari**

```
.checkBoxElement{
   -webkit-margin-before:10px;
}
```

**IE and safari**

```
::-ms-backdrop, .checkBoxElement {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**safari only**

```
 ::i-block-chrome, .checkBoxElement {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

or 

    ::i-block-chrome, .checkBoxElement {
        -webkit-margin-before: 10px;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work for chrome ! #showAllHistory{
    -webkit-margin-before:15px; 
} Gave something like this for chrome. Inside IE , I gave margin-left:10px;

Comment: @sahana other browser works or not?

Comment: in your css style sheet, initially add #showAllHistory{ margin-left:15px;} then add hack codes for other browsers

Comment: #showAllHistory{margin-left:15px;} @-moz-document url-prefix() {
#showAllHistory{margin-left : 10px; }}::-ms-backdrop, #showAllHistory {
    margin-left: 10px;} ::i-block-chrome, #showAllHistory{
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

Comment: I need only for chrome and IE !

Comment: @sahana simple u just add #showAllHistory{margin-left:15px;} then add ::-ms-backdrop, #showAllHistory {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

Comment: Thanks a ton. It works well. I also understood how to handle these kind of issues.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using something like [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/3.0.3/normalize.css), I would recommend it. This will allow you to have a cross-browser "blank slate" so that you don't need to make specific styles for certain browsers. If you can't incorporate an entire reset stylesheet into your project, copy the appropriate styles:

```
/**
 * It's recommended that you don't attempt to style these elements.
 * Firefox's implementation doesn't respect box-sizing, padding, or width.
 *
 * 1. Address box sizing set to `content-box` in IE 8/9/10.
 * 2. Remove excess padding in IE 8/9/10.
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}
```

Then pick your favorite way of aligning the checkbox.

Something like:

```
input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}
input[type=radio] {
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

Here's a live example:

```css
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio] {
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1px;
}
input[type=radio] {
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox"> hello</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, try the `-webkit-margin-left:10px;` & `-moz-margin-left:10px;`

Answer (score 0):

you can add another stylesheet for IE where you change the proper values.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normal-styles.css" type="text/css" />
<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="ie-fixes.css" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Conditional stylesheets doesn't work above IE 10 version.